# How to make clicking on the text in a radio input selects the corresponding button?

Tags: html, forms

Basically, just the text can be clicked to have the same effect as clicking the button in a form that has the input type as radio.

For example:

```
<input type="radio">(Random input)
```

That but instead of having to press the button, you just need to press the text (in this case "Random input")

This might be a stupid question but I am just starting to learn HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add code below.

-html

```
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Milk">
  Milk
</label>
```

label tag means that the browser'll treat everything in it as one element.

I think this answer will help you enoughly.